# how to select records based on recent date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables like below :

hr_emp_job_compensation:

```
    id   date          fkEmp_id  basic_wage    part_hours   part_amt

     1    04-01-2016    1            4500        35          120
     2    04-01-2016    3            3800        30          150
     3    08-01-2016    3            3200        30          100
```

hr_emp_job_info:

```
    id    fkEmp_id

     1      1
     2      3
```

hr_emp_info:

```
   id    employee_id   first_name

    1     001       Ram
    2     002       Lak
    3     003       jai
    4     004       shiva
```

I want to select  records from table 1 , based on the column Date value is higher.

I Try the following query :

```
SELECT t1.fkEmp_id,max(t1.date),max(t1.id) as uid,t1.part_hours,t1.part_amt, t3.first_name, t3.employee_id 
FROM `hr_emp_job_compensation` as t1 
inner join `hr_emp_job_info` as t2 on t1.fkEmp_id = t2.fkEmp_id 
left join `hr_emp_info` as t3 on t3.id = t1.fkEmp_id 
group by t1.fkEmp_id
```

But the result is look like below :

```
      fkEmp_id    max(t1.date)   uid  part_hours  part_amt  first_name  employee_id
        1          2016-01-04     1     35          120       Ram         001

        3          2016-01-08     3     30          150       Jai         003
```

Here the part_hours and part_amt  columns are fetched from the id 2. How to change the query.

Comment: Please fix your editing to include the actual tables.

Comment: More details, more answer. what table value and what results

Comment: I change my question . please help me

Comment: Also add your expected result in the post

Comment: So for `2016-01-08` you want the `part_hours` = 30 and `part_amt` = 100 in the result?

Comment: yes i want to get result by max date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add `MAX()` for the `date`and `id`. You can handle the `MAX(date)` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  t1.fkEmp_id, t1.date as `date`, t1.id as uid,
        t1.part_hours, t1.part_amt, 
        t3.first_name, t3.employee_id 
FROM `hr_emp_job_compensation` as t1 
INNER JOIN `hr_emp_job_info` as t2 on t2.fkEmp_id = t1.fkEmp_id
LEFT JOIN `hr_emp_info` as t3 on t3.id = t1.fkEmp_id 
WHERE t1.`date`= ( SELECT MAX(`date`) 
                   FROM `hr_emp_job_compensation` 
                   WHERE fkEmp_id = t1.fkEmp_id);
```

Please find the <kbd>[`Working Demo`](http://rextester.com/TUDP31940)</kbd>

Comment: But if  my table ( hr_emp_job_compensation) having  highest values of part_hours and part_amt  in the id 2 means what i want to do. i want to get the result by max date of hr_emp_job_compensation table

Comment: i change my question . please help me

Comment: I think you can now remove the `GROUP BY` clause.  You could also replace the `INNER JOIN` on t4 you added with `WHERE t1.date=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM hr_emp_job_compensation WHERE fkEmp_id=T1.fkEmp_id)`.  Sorry I'm struggling to add a reverse tick into a comment.

Comment: @Unoembre: Thanks for the suggestion, that makes sense. I updated in the answer.